# Firestore how to set serverTimestamp behaviour in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make my app save local changes (e.g. saving notes) to firestore db while it is offline. When I use `DateTime.now(`) for `timeCreated`, everything (most of job) works, but obviously, it is not correct time. I found solution with using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to have correct time, but once I try to use it while app is offline, I can't get a value of previous timeCreated fields. Furthermore, I found out about `DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior` in firebase docs, and now I don't have clue how to use it or is it even available in flutter mobile apps. Link for Android: [Android docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior).

**EDIT**

I already gave up from using serverTimestamp, but I gave it another shot and successfully solved it. The problem was that I used `hasPendingWrites`on whole query, instead on single document which is added (updated) offline. In this article everything is described [link](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestore-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b). Still, I didn't find solution for my question.

Comment: Link not working. check and fix it.

Comment: I know that this is obvious for you however can you tell why `DateTime.now()` gives "not correct" time? and generally means that time is incorrect?

Comment: @vitooh because it is device time, which user can manually change to anything.